# NestJS File Upload validator when file field is empty or does not exists

Tags: file, nestjs

I'm trying to validate if the file is really sent by the user into the correct field.

My controller should verify is the field "file" exists in the multipart form data and if a real file is associated to it and sent.

```
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    @Post('file/pass-validation')
    uploadFileAndPassValidation(
        @UploadedFile(
            /*new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
                .addFileTypeValidator({
                    fileType: 'jpeg',
                })
                .build({errorHttpStatusCode: 400}),*/
        )
        file: Express.Multer.File,
    ) {
        console.log(file)
        return true;
    }
```

Result with an empty form:

[Insomnia request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44m4B.png)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxn0f.png)

Expected output:
400 Bad request

Moreover, if I apply the pipe I have a 500 internal server error as it tries to apply function on a undefined file variable.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue and this is my solution:

I use custom `FileValidator` implementation to check if file is defined ([docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#file-validation)).

It throws error if `isValid` method returns false.

```js
import { FileValidator } from "@nestjs/common";

export class FileIsDefinedValidator extends FileValidator {
    constructor() {
        // parent class constructor requires any object as
        // argument, i think it is type mistake, so i pass
        // empty object
        super({});
    }

    isValid(file?: unknown): boolean {
        return !!file;
    }
    buildErrorMessage(): string {
        return "File is not defined";
    }
}
```

Use validator in `UploadedFile` decorator options:

```js
@Post("/uploads")
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor("file"))
async uploadImage(
    @UploadedFile(
        new ParseFilePipe({ validators: [new FileIsDefinedValidator()] }),
    )
    file: Express.Multer.File
) {
    // process file
}
```